# Shopify Image Hosting

Tags: shopify

Is it possible to use an image from a shopify site's hosting/server on another website? Say, Amazon?

If so, how do you link to it/what's the url for the image?  In order for it to be in the product listing, it would likely be something along these lines:

```
<p style="background: url(http://shopifysite.com/images/best-product-image.jpg) no-repeat; height: 354px; width: 1200px; "text-align:right";"></p>
```

Not sure if this is possible at all with Shopify's CDN image servers.  Fingers crossed it's workable.

Comment: Possible, yes. Polite/allowed, no idea? Maybe you should ask shoppify if they allow hotlinking their images, otherwise you can get nailed with theft of service.

Comment: Ah so that's what it's called.  I'm on support chat with Shopify now trying to see what, if any, stance they have on it.  Can you tell me how you would go about hotlinking it from them?

Comment: Got it squared away.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Spoke with Shopify and they pointed me to the part of the admin backend with the url image links for the files.

In the Shopify dashboard, simply go to settings>files> and next to the image file you want to use, there will be the image url.  Easy peezy (peazy??)

Also, you can do what I should have thought of at the beginning, which is to right click the image you want to use and copy the image url.  Either way.